# Reclassifying raster layer under condition

Tags: raster, qgis-3, reclassify

I have a raster layer with different landcover categories (on the left of the picture):

[image: this is my raster]

What I need is a layer that holds the information if there is forest or not to later combine it with the regions of my vector-layer. I would like to redefine the values to 1 for forest (categories 311, 312, 313) and all the others to 0.

How can I do that in QGIS 3 or with a Python script ?

I tried the expression for the raster calculator like Erik suggested:
"(mylayer@1=311) OR (mylayer@1=312) OR (mylayer@1=313)"
this is my result:
[image]
[image]

[image]

So... fortunately there are other raster-files available in the internet. I got a rasterfile from European Forest Institute that shows the forest-share already! I am glad I can go on with my analysis, but still I would like to understand why I couldn't reclassify with a table or calculate a new raster.

Comment: I erased the [tag:python-3] tag because no code snippets were provided (Otherwise your question can be closed)

Comment: Frame challenge: You can get the CLC as geopackage, which would allow you to use `select by expression` and omits fiddling with the raster calc. Would this be an option?

Comment: Yes, actually my first attempt was to work with the geopackage, but it is hard for my computer due to the big size... but I will try that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Head for the raster calculator and enter the following:

`(CLC@1=311) OR (CLC@1=312) OR (CLC@1=313)`

This assigns your CLC-layer a `1` where it is forest, and a `0` where the conditions aren't met. Be sure to replace `CLC@1` with the actual name of your CLC-layer. It will be listed in the raster calculator.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working as I expected (see picture).

Comment: @Carina which extent did you set the image to?

Comment: where? I didn' change anything else in the raster calculator...

Comment: @Carina at the top right you may set the extent. Make sure you highlight the CLC-layer in the list to the left, then click to button.

Comment: Now I set it to the extend of my inputlayer (with the button you mentioned), but still strange output ; ) see third picture ...

Comment: @Carina please provide the exact expression you're using on the raster calc. I recreated a CLC raster from my geopackage and run the expression, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for, is the processint tool "Reclassify by Table".

You find it in the Processing Toolbox (Processing -> Toolbox). Then just surch for "Reclassify by Table" or you will find it under the menu "Raster analysis".

Comment: Ahhhh, cool! I will try it this way! Tank you!

Comment: ... unfortunately the same outcome as with Eriks suggestion (3rd picture).

Answer (score 2):

Use Raster calculator. If an expression is true it evalutes to one, else zero so:

```
("nmd_bas_sub@1"=111)*1+("nmd_bas_sub@1"=112)*1+("nmd_bas_sub@1"=113)*1+0
```

will be 1 for class 111, 112 and 113, else it will be 0:

[image]

Comment: Again the same outcome (4th picture)... I tried to chang the way of its symbology, maybe ther is my mistake, but I couldn't find the error yet...

Comment: What expression are you using i raster calculator

Comment: Exactly what you suggested! ("mylayername@1"=111)*1+("mylayername@1"=112)*1+("mylayername@1"=113)*1+0

Comment: You need to change it to your raster name and values

Comment: `("u2018_bblablablablabla@1"=311)*1 + ...`

Comment: yes! the new raster only has "0" no "1"... like the other results...